# Is there any simple form for sum of even items of $(1+x)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-theorem

Consider the function $f(x) = (1+x)^n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^i, x > 1$ and $h(x) = (1-x)^n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(-x)^i, x > 1$, we are interested in the $x[f(x) + h(x)] + f(x) - h(x)$.

$f(x) + h(x)$ is 2* sum of even items of $f(x)$ while $f(x) - h(x)$ is 2* sum of odd items of $f(x)$. I am wondering if there is any simple form for the sum of even items or odd items?

Comment: You've pretty much derived the answer: the sum of the even-degree terms is $\frac12\big( (1+x)^n+(1-x)^n \big)$ and similarly for the sum of the odd-degree terms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to combine these two parts and obtain a simpler form since my $x$ is too complicated.

Comment: In my view, the two simplest forms for this function are the two you have already found (one from my comment and the other as an explicit sum of binomial coefficients).

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: You had typos in series expressions - corrected.

Comment: You are only missing one key insight yo simplify things: h(x)=f(-x). So the even other the odd elements are $(f(x)\pm f(-x))/2$.